# What does the term ほおほお mean?

Tags: meaning, words

I mentioned to a Japanese chat friend that I liked music after he asked me what I liked. He then typed ほおほお. Does it mean something similar to "I see."? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「ほおほお」 is an interjection used when one is impressed or surprised.  It roughly means "***Oh, is that right?***", "***Oh, I see.***", etc. depending on the context it is used in.

The dictionary spelling is 「ほうほう」 or just 「ほう」.

https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86

Answer (score 0):

「ほおほお」or「ほうほう」is used to represent the sound that Japanese people sometimes make to express that they are listening to the other person or understanding what he/she said. It is something like "uh-huh," but it is informal and isn't used when they are talking with a superior or older person.